# How to move each file into its own folder on Mac OS based on name

Tags: macos, automator, automation

So I have a folder filled with images with their file names as an accurate description. So for instance a Starbucks logo with name Starbucks. So I want to create a folder called Starbucks for this file and other which follow the same idea. How would I do this on Mac OS without doing it manually for hundreds of files? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For a commercial solution, you might give [Hazel](https://www.noodlesoft.com/) a look.

If you're handy with shell scripting, you could take something like this and adapt it. As is, it should process all PNG files in your Downloads folder, sorting them into folders based on the first word (up to the first non-alphabetic character) of the filename.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BASE="$HOME/Downloads"
while read -r FILE; do
  BN=${FILE##*/}
  FOLDER=${BN/[^a-zA-Z]*}
  [ -n "$FOLDER" ] || continue
  echo "moving $BN into $FOLDER"
  mkdir -p "$BASE/$FOLDER" 2>/dev/null
  mv -n "$FILE" "$BASE/$FOLDER/"
done < <(find "$BASE" -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.png")
```